# How to implement permalinks in a serverless Vue SPA

Tags: vue.js, url, vue-router

I made [this little app](https://sonofgeogif.netlify.app/) which is a simple Vue serverless SPA. I wish to pass an array of strings and a an array of numbers through the URL so that I can share "states" of the websites with colleagues. I understand `vue-router`can update the route's parameters as per their [documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html), but I do not have enough perspective to see how to implement this to solve my problem. I would love some help or guidance so I actually learn from this. Thank you all.

EDIT:  after Mr. Luis Brito's hint.
I added the following to my code (props)

```
const router = new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: require('@/views/Home').default,
      props: { myNumbers: [1,2,3]}
    },
  ]
})
```

in a component I did

```
mounted () {
  this.$router.push({ name: 'myNumbers', params: {myNumbers: [1,2,3,4] }})
  const myNumbers = this.$route.params.myNumbers
  console.log(myNumbers);
}
```

But now my App throws a Vue-Router error `[vue-router] Route with name 'myNumbers' does not exist` but it does console log the numbers I pushed. Is it possible to make my app look for props and only if they are there to do something with them? Otherwise I get a white screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I see to solve this problem is use `vue-router` with a route that passes `props` to the component, that `prop` can be an object containing the two arrays that you mentioned.

Referer to [Vue Router - Obect Mode](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#object-mode)

Here is an example for the router:

```
const routes = {
  path: '/promotion/from-newsletter',
    component: Promotion,
    props: { myNumbers: [1,2,3,5,8], myStrings: ['first', 'second', 'third'] 
  }
}
```

On the component side, you can access those `props` on `created()` lifecycle hook, or `mounted()`

```
props: ['myNumbers','myStrings '],
mounted() {
   if ( this.myNumbers !== undefined && this.myStrings !== undefined ) {
      console.log(thys.myNumbers, this.myStrings);
   }
}
```

So that `http://localhost:8080/?myStrings=layer1,layer2,layer3&myNumbers=-1,2,3-4` would console log layer 1-3 and the numbers.

EDITED

TO pass the values programatically, would be better to use [Function Mode](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#object-mode) to capture the URL params and pass it to component. Another way would be to create a component where you can input the numbers and strings that you want, and then call the router and pass those values to the route for the final destination component.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Brito, but I as my edit shows I am not quite certain how to implement this. Is there a way to make these props optional or ignore in my route? I get a white page.

Comment: Remove that line `this.$router.push({ name: 'myNumbers', params: {myNumbers: [1,2,3,4] }})` inside `mounted()`, that line are telling to the router to navigate to a route named `myNumbers` right after mount the component. 
The params are not mandatory, on component you can check if they exists, `if(this.$route.params.myNumbers !== null){...}`

Comment: How would I set the params from inside a component and do I need to add `props: ['myNumbers']` to my `script`?

Comment: Hmm, I see. So what you need is [Function Mode](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#object-mode) to pass props.
`{
  path: '/',
  name: 'home',
  component: require('@/views/Home').default,
  props: route => ({ myNumbers: route.query.numbers})
}`

After that, you can pass the numbers via URL, `http://localhost/?numbers=1,2,3,5,8`
You will need to convert the param to numbers, once they are received as strings

Comment: Another way would be to create a component from which you can input the numbers and string, and from it navigate to the final component passing the inputs as params.

Comment: The Function mode looks exactly like what i want to do but for some weird reason I do not get anything if I `console.log(this.$router.params)` inside my component when i go to  `http://localhost/?numbers=1,2,3,5,8`. I get an empty object.

Comment: There is a difference between `this.$route` and `this.$router`. To access the params, use `this.$route`, with no R at the end of the word. The `$route` refers to the current route, whilst `$router` refers to the mechanism that navigates to routes, the vue router (the router per se).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243569/discussion-between-yordan-radev-and-luis-brito).